# Media Player not able to stream Icecast2 url in < 4.1

Tags: android, icecast

I'm able to play Icecast2 url in 4.1+ versions, but in earlier versions it's throwing IOException.

I've used this code to play audio stream.

> ```
> try {
>     this.mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
>     this.mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
>     //this.mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,Uri.parse("http://176.31.115.196:8214/"));
>     this.mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse("http://184.107.191.197:8065/live"));
>     this.mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
>         public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
>             mp.start();
>         }
>     });
>     } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
>         Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException: " + e.getMessage());
>     } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {              
>         Log.d(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException: " + e.getMessage());
>     } catch (SecurityException e) {
>         Log.d(TAG, "SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
>     }
> ```

I got this Exception..

> error (1, -2147483648)
>    create failed:
>    java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
>           at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
>       at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:632)
>       at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:609)
>       at com.Rcc.Common.UserPublicData.createNewMediaPlayer(UserPublicData.java:170)
>       at com.Rcc.Submain.PlaySubview$PrepareStream.doInBackground(PlaySubview.java:837)
>       at com.Rcc.Submain.PlaySubview$PrepareStream.doInBackground(PlaySubview.java:1)
>       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
>    Exception: null

The other url works fine, only problem with the icecast url.
Please nothe that url works fine in JellyBean versions.